# How to check if a key corresponds to a value in a HashMap in Rust?

Tags: rest, rust, hashmap

I reckon that there is contains_key() method for this purpose, but I am getting error as I want to use Some and None which has boolean as return value. get() method works fine for the opposite state which is finding a value that corresponds to a key. The main goal is to create an endpoint for finding a key by value and the opposite. I have come up to the following logic for finding the value but am stuck with finding the key:

```rust
fn main() {
    use std::collections::HashMap;

    let mut my_info: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    my_info.insert("Brad".to_string(), "Pitt".to_string());
    my_info.insert("Tom".to_string(), "Cruise".to_string());

    match my_info.get("Brad") {
        Some(firstname) => println!("Last Name: {}", firstname),
        None => println!("FIRST NAME NOT FOUND")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your wording is hard to follow, but are you asking how to use `"Pitt"` to get `"Brad"` as a result?

Comment: If your question is, indeed, as @kmdreko asks, I think the general solution to this is to create two maps, (for example) one that maps first names to last names, and a "reverse map" mapping those same last names back to first names.

Comment: @kmdreko yes, i want to use "Pitt" to get "Brad".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly. `HashMap`s are all about going from a `key` to a `value`. What you can do here, is to have two `HashMap`s, one for `key` to `value` and the other for `value` to `key`. Note: this means that the `key` and `value` will be independent and change in one will not change the other. Moreover, it means that they will be different objects which can double your memory usage / take a lot of time / might not be possible. You will also need both the `key` and `value` to be unique and hashable. The code can be something like this:

```rust
struct BiMap<K, V> {
  key_val: HashMap<K, V>,
  val_key: HashMap<V, K>
}

impl<K, V> BiMap<K, V> {
  pub fn get_by_key(&self, key: &K) -> Option<V> {
    self.key_val.get(key)
  }

  pub fn get_by_val(&self, val: &V) -> Option<K> {
    self.val_key.get(val)
  }
}
```

(There are very likely some type errors there. Follow the compiler messages / `Hashmap::get`'s signature to fix them.)

Another way, if you cannot do the above / do not want to do the above, is to iterate through the whole hashmap, comparing the values and returning the key when you find it. The code will be somewhat like this:

```rust
my_info.iter().find(|(_, v)| v == last_name).map(|(first_name, _)| first_name)
```

This will give you the `first_name` of the first person to have the `last_name` specified.

Answer (score 0):

There's a crate for bi-directional maps: https://docs.rs/bidirectional-map/0.1.0/bidirectional_map/